# Why is this double null?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, performance, google-maps

I' m in a service, and I just need the latitude and longitude. Just two doubles. So, I did the following:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
}
```

For some reason, the latitude and latitude are null. The documentation says this is possible if the information for location is unavailable, but it should be available, since I first check if the permissions are there in the if statement, right? In the phone that I am testing on, I do have location enabled. **Why is the latitude and longitude null?**

Comment: (`For some reason, the latitude and latitude are` identical :-) `should be available, since I first check if the permissions are there` seems to take _accessible_ for _available_.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you are checking last known location, and if there were no locations previously fetched by this provider, all corresponding parameters will be `null`. Method `getLastKnownLocation` reuses information fetched by other apps/services, and it can happen that there were no information saved.

You can try to make single location update using method `requestSingleUpdate`, so you won't depend on your device state.

Comment: What do I invoke the `requestSingleUpdate` method on? Also, do you think I am doing this the best way? All I want is the **most accurate** location (latitude and longitude) of the user that I **can** get, should I be doing it like this? Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: What parameters should I put in requestSingleUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

It's because, even if location is enabled, there is no "lastKnownLocation" available yet. If you go to (for example) google maps app and ask for current location, after location is successfully fetched, go to your app and it will work (lat and lon != null).

EDIT: I don't know the code for android location service API, but for google maps API is something like this (i'm sure is similar):

```
public void methodThatUseLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS, MainActivity.REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            Double latitude = lastLocation.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = lastLocation.getLongitude();

            // do something with latitude and longitude
        } else {
            requestLocationUpdate();
        }
    }
}

private void requestLocationUpdate() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS, MainActivity.REQUEST_LOCATION);
    } else {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: So how can I get the current location? All I want is the **most accurate** location (latitude and longitude) of the user that I **can** get.

Comment: as I mentioned, this code is for Google Maps SDK, not default Android Locations API.. I'm sure the concept is very similar, take a look at the docs and find some similar method (requestSingleUpdate?)

Answer (score 0):

If you try this instead, what is the output?
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);